# Text displays different size on iphone

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios

On an existing website, one block of text is displaying too large on an iPhone, and part of it is white. I've tested it on Android and on an iPad, which pushes the rest of the site down too far, so it doesn't line up with the background. It is the proper size on an iPad, but still showing up white. The text in question is in the top right corner on this page: http://www.ecodzign.com/waterfx2/index2.html
This is how it looks on an iphone:

[image]

I've disabled text scaling, and I've tried using inline css, with no effect. Only phone numbers are displaying white, so I assume the iphone is creating some sort of link to call those numbers with the phone, but regardless, that can't be white with a white background.

I apologize for the awful table design and lack of validation, but I'm simply not budgeted to redo the entire site properly. There are no validation errors that have to do with text or formatting, I doubt that has anything to do with what is going on.

Comment: I'll try defining it in pixels instead of points and add !important and report back when I get access to an iPhone

Comment: I figured out the white phone number problem. The iPhone converts any detected phone numbers into links, using whatever styles the site has for links, in this case, to make them white. The solution is to change default color for links in that part of the site, or break up the phone number with a tag, preventing the iPhone from turning it into a link (I.E. 702.<span>555</span>.1212

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be the difference between things like `pt` vs `px` vs `%` on your iOS device for that specific block.

After checking your code, I think this is it in fact:

```
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 8pt;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
```

The `font-size: 8pt` I would bet is the culprit.

Comment: You just need to be consistent with your CSS, mixing just gets you into trouble when you consider cross browser/device

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be a lot of inline CSS on the site.

What it you tried this

`<span style="color:black !important;">702.233.3200</span>`

utilizing the `!important` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

That most likely has to do with the CSS of the website. Your best option would be to create a mobile friendly site or removing **`<span style='color:black;'>`** from the html that wraps these numbers.